# jasmine-maven-plugin load some other test utilities common script

Tags: javascript, jasmine, phantomjs, jasmine-maven-plugin

I have multiple tests that need to share the same common utilities script. I wouldn't want to place this file in the source folder structure, since it's only relevant for testing.

So my source folder is:

```
<jsSrcDir>${project.basedir}/src/main/js</jsSrcDir>
```

and my test source:

```
<jsTestSrcDir>src/test/js</jsTestSrcDir>
```

In src/test/js I have a testUtil.js file that I need to load in other jasmine tests. Is it possible to access such files from within a jasmine test?

```
describe('Load Util Module', function() {
    it('check util is loaded', function() {
        //load testUtil.js
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I managed to do it:

1. I added [require.js](http://requirejs.org/) to my specs folder

   ```
   src/test/js/require.js
   ```
2. In the jasmine-maven-plugin configuration I added the REQUIRE_JS spec runner template:

   ```
   <specRunnerTemplate>REQUIRE_JS</specRunnerTemplate>
   ```
3. The data file is located in:

   ```
   src/test/js/testUtil.js
   ```

   having the following content:

   ```
   define([], function() {
       return {
           "data" : [1, 2, 3]
       };
   });
   ```
4. The tests to be injected this data object require a define directive:

   ```
   define(['../../../spec/testUtil'], function(testUtil) {
       var _testUtil = testUtil;
       describe('Testing data loaded', function () {
           it('loads test data', function () {            
                expect(testUtil.data.length).toBe(3);
            });
       });
   });
   ```

Answer (score 0):

If you were not already using require.js for your project then your solution is overkill.

You just need to use the preloadSources configuration parameter if you want to be sure your library loads before your specs.

```
<preloadSources>
  <source>src/test/js/testUtil.js</source>
<preloadSources>
```

Comment: But my test data scripts should reside in the test folder. It's not a good practice to mix source files with test data, common mock data or test utilities.